# Background image not appearing in CSS using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I'm fairly new to web development and have been trying to make a website using Bootstrap, hosted on github.  The bootstrap theme I'm using has a header section which I'm trying to cover with a background image (it was originally just a solid color), however the image doesn't appear.

Here is my code:
HTML - header section:

```
<header class="masthead" id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/headshot.png" alt="Headshot">
      <div class="intro-text">
        <span class="name">NAME</span>
        <hr class="star-light">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header.masthead {
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  background: #148ABC;}

#banner {
  background-image: url("/img/banner.jpg") no-repeat center; 
  background-size: cover; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
```

My `"banner.jpg"` file which is the background image is located in at "img" folder, which is in the same directory as a "css" folder that contains the actual css file. I've tried the following:

- changing the url to "/img/banner.jpg", "../img/banner.jpg" and "img/banner.jpg" (I think the first one is still right?)
- removing the #banner id and putting everything in css under header.masthead alone
- deleting the width and height
- double checking the name of the file (it is banner.jpg)

I've been working on this for days so I'm pretty frustrated with myself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: folder path "../img/banner.jpg" is the right one.

Comment: Silly qustion - Have you cleared the browser's cache?

Comment: I've done both, but it hasn't helped unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with this snippet , i have changed `background-image` to `background` and remove the `background color` of the header

```css
header.masthead {
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
}

#banner {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg") center center no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
```

```html
<header class="masthead" id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/headshot.png" alt="Headshot">
      <div class="intro-text">
        <span class="name">NAME</span>
        <hr class="star-light">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks so much, this works! any idea why I can't just put an image as background cover over a background color?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `no-repeat and cover` on `background-image` as they are property of `background`. So you can have only image `url` on `background-image`.

And also try removing fallback `background` on `header.masthead`.

Try below [fiddler][1] for reference.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/qcwvet4p/
```

Comment: This didn't work.  Now I've got a white page with no image as well

Comment: If your files are located like this, 
html--root-->  
css--root-->css-->  
image--root-->img-->

Then you are suppose to use ../img/image.format